# Remove first n-1 zeros from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df_in` is the sample dataframe and `df_out` is the expected output.

How do I remove the first 5 zeros so that I have one zero and all other elements.

```
import pandas as pd

df_in = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2]})

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2]})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates()` ??

Comment: @anky_91 but it will remove other duplicate values too.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar exactly, but we dont know yet what values should be removed and what not. The question is not very clear thatway. based on the expected output it looks as a clear `drop_duplicates()` case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the value and remove duplicates then concat with others

```
pd.concat([df_in.loc[df_in.a == 0, :].drop_duplicates(), df_in.loc[df_in.a != 0,:]])
```